# How to sort the files by "Data Modified" in IIS Server 7.5?

Tags: iis

I have enabled 'Directory Browsing' for only "logs" folder of my Web Application hosted via IIS 7.5 
Whenever I type www.domain.name//logs in my Browser, I could see the log files listed.

I would like to see the files sorted by 'Date Modified',i.e, the latest log must come at top and the oldest log must be present at the bottom.
How to go about this?
Is this possible in IIS 7.5 in first place?

Comment: From my end, I have tried logging into the Web Server directly, once inside the directory, click the 'Date Modified' column at the top to sort the files. But still when the request comes from the browser, all I could see is the unsorted log files returned for display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no out of box setting/configuration available with which you can sort directory/file list displayed in browser. Of course that doesn't stop you writing your own custom HTTP module. Here is broad idea.

1. Intercept directory requests to your application.
2. In Http module handle OnPreRequestHandlerExecute event.
3. In even handler get directory/file list.
4. Create nicely formatted page which will display list from step 3. Here you can format/sort way you like it.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. I could understand 4th Step. Just in case if you have anything to share on how to implement Step 1,2 and 3, I would really appreciate it, as I am newbie to Web Development and I also believe that brings this post to a logical end.